# CollectionView Filter slow after first run

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionviewsource

When filtering a CollectionView of about 1000 items, I am running into some serious speed issues.

I am essentially having the user select from a list of items, there is a button that allows them to select/deselect all the items at once.  The very first time this button is pressed, the filtering takes < 1 second.  ALL subsequent filterings take an upwards of 10 seconds.

Here is the relevant code

```
//Assume that these call PropertyChanged as needed
public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; } 
public CollectionViewSource SelectedItems { get; set; }  

public void LoadItems()
{
    Items = GetItemsFromDatabase();
    SelectedItems = new CollectionViewSource()
    {
        Source = Items,
        IsLiveFilteringRequested = true,
        LiveFilteringProperties = { "IsSelected" }
    };
    SelectedItems.Filter += (src, args) =>
    {
        var item = args.Item as Item;
        args.Accepted = item != null && item.IsSelected; 
    };
}

public void SelectAll()
{
    using (SelectedItems.DeferRefresh())
    {
        Items.ForEach(f => f.IsSelected = true);
    }
}

public void DeselectAll()
{
    using (SelectedItems.DeferRefresh())
    {
        Items.ForEach(f => f.IsSelected = false);
    }
}
```

The view is a simple Data Grid

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <!-- etc -->
</DataGrid>
```

The filtering is as simple as it can be, just a single `IsSelected` boolean, I am not sure what exactly is causing such a huge slowdown.

`SelectAll` and `DeselectAll` run almost instantly.
The slowdown is happening *between* each call to the `Filter` event on `CollectionViewSource`.

Any advice?

Comment: What you have here I think is an O(n^2) operation.  So if 1000 items takes 10 seconds then 2000 items would take 100 seconds and 4000 items would take about 3 hours.  Would be an interesting test.  The problem I think is that your filter is scanning the entire list each time a single selection is toggled.  So for 1000 items the filter would scan the list 1 million times.  No idea why the first time is different...perhaps filter not yet engaged?  Turn off filter before setting or resetting entire list.  Turn it back on at the end.

Comment: @AQuirky I don't see how this would be O(n^2), it's iterating over a single list one time, at most it should be O(n).  And yes, the filter is definitely engaged the first time, the items don't appear in the "selected" datagrid until I press the "select all" button.  The first time it's almost instant.  If the filter was not engaged, the list would contain all the items from the start.

Comment: Very easy to test my theory:  put 2000 items in the list.  Event showers create O(n^2) situations all the time and this code says event shower to me. I'll test it myself later if I get a chance.